# WebView preload

Tags: react-native, webview

I have screen with the button, after pressing the button, opens another component with `WebView`, `WebView` is loading very slow. I want to speed up the process and start loading `WebView` in the first screen and display it only in case if user will clicks on the Button. How to do that correctly?

My WebView:

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: linkFullStory}}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}>
                        </WebView>
```

Comment: One way to do this is to include the WebView component as hidden first (e.g. place it off screen or behind another full screen component), then display it later. I wanted to preload the WebView that was using `react-navigation` though, and I couldn't figure out how to do that.